# Display data from Json in Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, json

First of all, I have to say that is my first time posting on StackOverflow.. So if I post on the wrong area, sorry.

I'm beginning with angularjs, and I'm struggling into two points. 1st I've to create a connection with my mysql, witch i wasn't able until now.. 2nd I've to display the content into the HTML page.

I'm using the following code, witch includes the app.js, page.html and data.json (I'll change that later to php if I'm allowed to.)
The app.js seems to work fine, but the view (page.html) isn't display any data..

### App.js

```
    app.controller('PatientListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('patients.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.patients = data;
    });
    $scope.orderProp = 'id';
}]);
```

### patients.json

```
[
    {
        "id": 0, 
        "first_name": "John", 
        "last_name": "Abruzzi"
    }, 
     {
        "id": 1, 
        "first_name": "Peter", 
        "last_name": "Burk"
    }
]
```

### Page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div data-ng-repeat="patient in patients">
        {{patient.id}}{{patient.last_name}}{{patient.first_name}}{{patient.SSN}}{{patient.DOB}}      
        <div>

    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: You call a "patients.json" file in your controller, but named it data.json in your exemple, is that normal ?

Comment: My bad, the file actually is named patients.json. I'll edit my post. Thank you for the reminder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not define the controller in the view

```
<div ng-controller="PatientListCtrl" data-ng-repeat="patient in patients">
       <li> {{patient.id}} </li>
  <div>
```

Here is the working [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/cy0wu24u/2/)

Comment: @Fred.Dutra welcome, mark as answer if it had helped you

Comment: Be sure I'll! Although idk if I can (low points I guess). Give my 3 min and I'll find out :D